# Signo de Interrogación en archivo .css y .js

Tags: javascript, variables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estimados un cordial saludo,

Alguien conoce a qué se debe que un archivo de css o javascript, tenga el signo de interrogación; como si se tratara de un envío de variables, sin embargo al quitar dicho parámetro, no ocurre ningún cambio en la página, aparentemente.

Muchas Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Las imagenes no deben ser usadas como codigo, deberias editar la pregunta y poner simplemente el texto como codigo.

Comment: Es un parámetro pasado por la URL, cuando se quiere que el navegador interprete una página como no visitada se pone ese signo o se configura las directivas del servidor

Comment: Muchas veces se agrega algún parámetro en archivos CSS y JS para que el navegador cargue las últimas modificaciones, forzando a no usar lo que esté guardado en caché. Lo que sigue a `?` generalmente es arbitrario, pero puedes usar la fecha de última modificación, versión del archivo o cualquier otra cosa que se te ocurra, siempre que el navegador "crea" que se trata de un nuevo archivo.

Comment: Ahora que caigo en cuenta... es cierto lo que dice Triby, aveces cuando quieres forzar a que se recargue un archivo eso hacen los desarroladores.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Triby, por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Son claves y valores de peticion `GET`, aquello a lo que se refiere es que se pueden pasar parametros por `URL` donde luego el navegador podra hacer uso de esta informacion en la misma pagina extrayendo esos parametros.

Normalmente son usadas por paginas que utilizan `PHP`, ya que al pasar parametros de peticion `GET` se extraen mas o menos asi para luego usarse:

```
$nombre = $_GET["nombre"];
$edad = $_GET["edad"];
$xcosa = $_GET["xcosa"];
```

Esto en una `URL` parametrizada se veria mas o menos asi:

```
?nombre=Juan%20Anuel&edad=20&xcosa=xcosa
```

De manera simple y sencilla podriamos decir que una peticion `GET` es una de las formas mas faciles y rapidas de pasar informacion de una pagina a otra, sin embargo OJO

**ES LA MENOS SEGURA**

Ya que hay otro tipo de peticion, la peticion tipo **POST**, esta peticion es mas segura porque no deja rastro en la `URL`, es decir, por mas de que cambies la `URL`, no va a haber ninguna afectacion.

Entre que peticion usar o no eso dependera de lo siguiente:

- GET: usala cuando los parametros que vayas a enviar no sean sensibles o que no vaya a repercutir en la pagina su modificacion.
- POST: usala cuando los parametros que vayas a enviar sean de caracter sensibles o personales y que repercutan en la pagina, por ejemplo, nombre de usuario, clave, etc.

Asi que porfavor usa con cuidado la peticion `GET`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Riven, entiendo lo que mencionas. Sin embargo, en los archivos .css y .js no se está usando ninguna función para obtener dichos parámetros, es por ello mi duda. Por ejemplo, mandan un archivo: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../prueba/prueba.css?1"/>, pero el archivo: prueba.css,, contiene sólo clases "css" y en ningún momento utilizan el parámetro "1".

Comment: Es que como te digo, normalmente estos parametros los usa el servidor, en este caso puede ser PHP, y pues no se puede ver el codigo PHP desde el navegador, por este motivo quizas no veas que se este usando en ninguna parte, en el caso de css... me parece un tanto curioso...